# Change subtitle font size with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, parameters

I’m able to change the `FontName` when hardcoding subtitles with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -i temp.mp4 -vf subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='FontName=Roboto-Condensed-Bold' output.mp4
```

but unable to change the `FontSize`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i temp.mp4 -vf subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='FontName=Roboto-Condensed-Bold,FontSize=26' output.mp4
```

This returns `Unknown option FontSize` or `No option name near '26'` depending on the ffmpeg version.

Why? I thought `FontSize` was one of the accepted parameters.

Comment: ummmmm I'm not THAT familiar with ffmpeg, but I think you've mistook the `:` mark with `,`, just one character before "FontSize".

Comment: So, something like that: `ffmpeg -y -i temp.mp4 -vf subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='FontName=Roboto-Condensed-Bold:FontSize=26' output.mp4`

Comment: Also, You're using the ' mark after the "FontSize" flag, insted of closing it beforehand. So, newer solution: `ffmpeg -y -i temp.mp4 -vf subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='FontName=Roboto-Condensed-Bold':FontSize=26 output.mp4`

Comment: Last recommendation, for general CLI usage: Try to group strings together with `" "` marks. Like that: `ffmpeg -y -i temp.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='FontName=Roboto-Condensed-Bold':FontSize=26" output.mp4`

Comment: @Netan no all the examples I’ve seen use the comma (see https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24207/ffmpeg-hardcoded-subtitles-from-the-top-bigger-with-thicker-stroke-on-a-dark for instance) BUT there were some forgotten quotes : ```!ffmpeg -y -i temp.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='FontName=Roboto-Condensed-Bold,FontSize=26'" output.mp4```

Comment: @Sulli It's probably an FFmpeg version issue (the syntax is correct). The following command is working for me in Windows 10: `ffmpeg -y -i temp.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subtitles.srt:fontsdir='c\:/Windows/Fonts/Roboto Condensed Bold.ttf':force_style='FontName='Roboto Condensed',FontSize=72'" output.mp4` (after installing `Roboto Condensed Bold.ttf` font file for all users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these quotes fix it:

```
ffmpeg -y -i temp.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='FontName=Roboto-Condensed-Bold,FontSize=26'" output.mp4
```

Also be careful, with some ffmpeg versions, the expected FontName could be "Roboto Condensed Bold" (without hyphens).